# Fail with error 'Min return not reached'

Tags: solidity, erc-20, etherscan, gas-price, error

I am trying to make trades on 1inch and frequently get an error that reads `Fail with error 'Min return not reached'`.

My gas prices are set very high because I need these trades to be as fast as possible.

An example:
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x8039dafe89764890903fbaf7deddcccd92935cf4e09ff346319280a67c1940e0

Does anyone know what this means and how to fix it?

Comment: did you give this  "minReturn = 73018254570675755" manually or as a percent? the code is written in assembly and really overwhelming so I'm just giving a guess here. The error comes in this line of code "lt(returnAmount, minReturn)" which probably means the returnAmount (I guess the actual number or token you got from swapping) is less than the expected min amount you are wanting to have

Comment: I have the same problem here, any way to solve? https://etherscan.io/tx/0xa9a150efcb8ed43cdac2c30ff4a7c7ea551716d2b8449326f66d6826fea99507